# How to cycle through array one at a time with button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is my code so far. My professor said I can not hard code. Can you please help me with the loop under the button click event. Right the flash form will load and pull up the first term and definition in the text files but when you click the next button it shows the path of the file that has been read in.

```
Public Class frmFlash

    Private _intSizeOfArray As Integer = 3
    Private _strLocationOfTerms(_intSizeOfArray) As String
    Private _strLocationOfDefinitions(_intSizeOfArray) As String
    Private _objReader As IO.StreamReader
    Private _strTerms As String

    Private Sub frmFlash_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
        Dim strLocationOfTerms As String = "C:\Users\boone\Desktop\Terms.txt"
        Dim strLocationOfDefinitions As String = "C:\Users\boone\Desktop\Definitions.txt"
        Dim intTermArray(4) As Integer
        Dim intCount As Integer

        lblDefinition.Visible = False   

        If IO.File.Exists(strLocationOfTerms) Then
            objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strLocationOfTerms)    
            _strTerms = objReader.ReadLine()    
            lblTerm.Text = _strTerms    
        End If

        If IO.File.Exists(strLocationOfDefinitions) Then
            objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strLocationOfDefinitions)

            strLocationOfDefinitions = objReader.ReadLine()

            objReader.Close()
            lblDefinition.Text = strLocationOfDefinitions
        End If   
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        Dim objReader(_intSizeOfArray) As IO.StreamReader
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0
        Dim strTermArray As String
        Dim strLocationOfTerms As String = "C:\Users\boone\Desktop\Terms.txt"
        Dim strLocationOfDefinitions As String = "C:\Users\boone\Desktop\Definitions.txt"

        Do While intCount <= _intSizeOfArray
            lblTerm.Text = strLocationOfTerms(_strTerms)
            lblDefinition.Text = strLocationOfDefinitions
            intCount += 1    
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDefinition_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDefinition.Click
        lblDefinition.Visible = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with arrays, the easiest way to do this is to skip the processing in the button handler entirely.  Load up your arrays in the `Load` event and just grab an `IEnumerator` for them.

```
'In Class level declarations
Private _termsEnumerator As IEnumerator(Of String)
Private _defsEnumerator As IEnumerator(Of String)

Private Sub frmFlash_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Your other initialization code...
    '...
    'Load your _strLocationOfTerms and _strLocationOfTerms here.
    _termsEnumerator = _strLocationOfTerms.GetEnumerator()
    _defsEnumerator = _strLocationOfDefinitions.GetEnumerator()
End Sub
```

Then it's just as simple as grabbing the next item from the arrays (they implement `IEnumerable`):

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If _termsEnumerator.MoveNext() And _defsEnumerator.MoveNext() Then
        lblTerm.Text = _termsEnumerator.Current
        lblDefinition.Text = _defsEnumerator.Current
    End If
End Sub
```